# (first) cohomology $H^1$ of sheaves on curves

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, sheaf-theory, curves, sheaf-cohomology

Say we have a reduced, irreducible, complete curve $X$ over a field $k$ and a sheaf $\mathcal F$ on $X$. I am interested in understanding the cohomology groups of $\mathcal F$.

By flat base change, we can assume $k$ is algebraically closed and by Grothendieck's vanishing theorem, $H^i(X,\mathcal F)$ is zero for $i\ge 2$. So the interesting information (if any) is reflected in $H^0$ and $H^1$, in particular $\chi(\mathcal F)=h^0-h^1$. $H^0$ is just the global sections.

If anything up to here is incorrect please correct me. I am not fully comfortable with the topic.

This leaves $H^1$. How should I think of $H^1$ (or $h^1$)? I know it is the ''obstruction'' to exactness of $\Gamma(X,\cdot)$, but  that doesn't quite help me visualize it.

In the particular instance of what I am reading, $\mathcal F$ is a torsion-free coherent $\mathcal O_X$-Module and it is assumed that $h^0=h^1=0$. If the above is correct, all cohomology groups thus vanish (since we are on a curve). Does this ''mean'' anything? (or should I just take it as a given and continue reading until hopefully it becomes clear)

Thank you.

Comment: Continue reading. You will see how cohomology is used and develop an intuiion for what it is.

Comment: There are at least two ways to think of $H^1(F)$. First, (on a smooth projective curve $X$) via Serre duality it is equal to $H^0(F^\vee(K_X))$. Second, it classifies extensions $0 \to F \to F' \to O_X \to 0$. Both ways are useful.

Comment: If $\mathcal{F}=\mathcal{O}_X^{\times},H^1\left(X,\mathcal{O}_X^{\times}\right)$ classifies the line bundles on $X$.